# How can you prove generalised Jacobi identity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

This

$$[A, [B,C]] + [C, [A,B]] + [B, [C,A]] = 0$$

This [proof](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~pavl/Jacobi.pdf) is not wanted, since there is an attachment of some variables.

**How can you prove the equation?**

Comment: Is $[\cdot,\cdot]$ supposed to be the Poisson bracket as it is in the proof you referenced or do you mean the quantum mechanical commutator?

Comment: In general you can't. But if [,] is the commutator, why dont just just expand the Jacobi formula?

Comment: I'd consider this a math question.

Comment: Comments to the question (v1): Echoing Jonas's comment, is this a question about Poisson brackets or operator commutators? The proof is very different depending on which. And what is 'generalized' about the Jacobi identity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the definition of the QM commutator $[X,Y]=XY-YX$, then expand all the commutators and simplify.